# 1000V MELF Diode Intermittent Failure. Diode shows degrading reverse voltage characteristics

Tags: diodes, analysis, failure

Hello to the electronics community in this forum. I am currently facing a MELF diode intermittent failures. These diodes failed when the final assembly (potted) is tested in a functional test after just 2 minutes of running. The diodes were then removed from the assembly and tested using an oscilloscope, where it showed a spike.

The diode was then tested using a curve tracer, where it shows degrading reverse voltage characteristic. Few diodes were used for an experiment where it included milling off 0.2mm of the surface of the diode to remove "contaminent", washing in DI water, washing in isopropanol, baking for 8hours at 200C and baking for 12hours at 100C.

The milling of the surface of the diode, washing with DI water and Isopropanol failed to revert the diode back to the original reverse voltage characteristic. However both baking the diodes makes the diode revert back to its good reverse voltage characteristic.

This clearly indicates that the diode has moisture trapped during the manufacturing process. My question here is how do I prove this is caused by moisture? Which types of experiments are suited to proof the moisture?

Need professional advise on how to move forward.

Comment: How do you know the potting isn't causing your problems?

Comment: I don't think you've proved anything.   Chances of water getting into the package, or of you being able to 'bake it out', are unlikely.  MELF packages are hermetically sealed plastic or glass.  Their whole purpose is to keep stuff out.   Note PCB's are often washed IN WATER after the reflow process and come out just fine.  Often when semiconductors fail, its because the bonding wires pull off the die. Your heating could have 'moved things around'.   Your best bet, give the defective samples to the diode manufacturer for analysis.  They'll have x-ray machines and such. (If they care to dig..)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_electrode_leadless_face          "Technical advantages
Despite their handling difficulties, and in the particular case of MELF resistors, they are still widely used in high-reliability and precision applications where their predictable characteristics (e.g., low failure rate with well-defined failure modes) as well as their higher performance in terms of accuracy, long-term stability, MOISTURE RESISTANCE, high-temperature operation far outweigh their disadvantage"

Comment: This isn't a forum. It's a question and answer site and lengthy discussion is frowned upon.

Comment: We rule out potting from testing the failed samples resistance. Using high voltage tester to test the conductivity of the potting material. The MELF Diode is not a wire bond diode. Its the common PN Junction, with Silicone chip. They have been manufactured in a non vacuum environment causing voids in the solder in between the Si-Chip and Junctions, hence why suspected it could be moisture. Sending the diodes to mfg for FA, resulted in two contradicting reports for two different customers. Another manufacturer are facing the same problem, with different potting compound used with same diode.